# How to click an element based on another element's text

Tags: automated-tests, selector, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

Given a multiple row user table...

```
<tr>
  <td class="cell--select">
    <input class="choice__input" type="checkbox">
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class="user">
      <ul class="user-info">
        <li class="name">Jane Doe</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr><tr>
...
```

I want to select the row with a given username and click the checkbox on that row. I've tried a number of ways to do this including `withText` and/or `parent()` and/or `find()` etc... but nothing works.

Typically, I would grab all the `li.name`s, check for the correct name and use the index to check the correct checkbox but I also can't figure out a way to accomplish that.

Stuck... ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a bit simpler way to achieve the desired behavior. You can use the [withText](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/functional-style-selectors.html#withtext) method to identify a table row:

```
const checkboxToClick = await Selector('tr')
  .withText('Jane Doe')
  .find(".choice__input");

await t.click(checkboxToClick);
```

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I found a way. This is a bit more brittle than I'd like but it works. Please *do* add an answer if there's a better solution!

```
const checkboxToClick = await Selector('.name')
      .withText('Jane Doe')
      .parent("tr")
      .find(".choice__input");

await t.click(checkboxToClick);
```